# A counterexample on compactness (closed vs complete)

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

In a metric space $M$:

If $A \subset M$ is complete and for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a compact $K \subset M$ with $A \subset \{ x \in M : d_M(x, K) \leq \epsilon \}$ then $A$ is compact.

Why is "$A$ is closed" not enough?

**Edit**: 
Is there a counterexample when $M$ is a normed vector space?

Comment: Let $M = (0,1)$ with the usual metric, and $A = (0,1/2]$.

Comment: And if $M$ is a normed vector space? (In connection with norm limits of compact operators)

Comment: Consider $\Bbb N\subset\Bbb R$.

Comment: @JonathanY: I don't think this works (with the euclidean metric)

Comment: @user66081 I might've misunderstood what you were looking for. Of course, DanielFischer's answer is great, but $\Bbb R$ is a Banach space, and $\Bbb N$ a complete ($\iff$ closed) subset (which is nonetheless not compact, as it's not even bounded). But perhaps $\Bbb R\subset\Bbb R^2$ is simpler (for being a closed subspace)?

Comment: @JonathanY. It seems you missed the approximability of $A$ by compact sets (aka total boundedness).

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I was trying to convey why closedness isn't enough regardless of $M$ being normed (it has nothing to do with it, but your example above wasn't aimed at showing that). Not as eloquently as you did below, granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a compact metric space is complete, the completeness of $A$ is a necessary requirement.

If the ambient space $M$ is itself complete, then for subsets $A\subset M$ the two properties of being closed and of being complete coincide, so in that case you can replace "complete" with "closed".

If $M$ is not complete, you cannot replace "complete" with "closed".

The condition that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a compact $K$ such that $A \subset B_\varepsilon(K)$ is another way of saying that $A$ is totally bounded, and a totally bounded metric space is compact if and only if it is complete. In a non-complete metric space, there are always closed but not complete totally bounded subsets, for example the underlying set of a non-convergent Cauchy sequence is closed and totally bounded, but not complete.

Comment: I didn't think of the "set of non-convergent Cauchy sequences", thanks

Comment: I found exactly what I was looking for in your answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440697/is-the-limit-of-compact-operators-again-compact